# If super() is called with arguments good for my immediate superclass, why can it then try to pass those arguments to a different class?

Tags: python

I am trying to build classes subject to the following inheritance relation:

> Person -> Student -> UniversityStudent -> GraduateStudent -> GradTA  
>      \                                                                                                   ^
>       \---------------------------------> Teacher ----------------------------------/

**My code**:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school):
        super().__init__(age,name)
        self.school = school

class UniversityStudent(Student):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school,major):
        super().__init__(age,name,school)
        self.major = major

class GraduateStudent(UniversityStudent):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school,major,advisor):
        super().__init__(age,name,school,major)
        self.advisor = advisor

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school,subject):
        super().__init__(age,name)
        self.school = school
        self.subject = subject

class GradTA(GraduateStudent,Teacher):
    def __init__(self,name,age,school,subject,major,advisor):
        GraduateStudent.__init__(self,age,name,school,major,advisor)
        Teacher.__init__(self,age,name,school,subject)

x = GradTA(name="Peter",school="Harvard",age=25,subject="Linear Algebra",major="Mathematics",advisor="Yau")
```

**Error message**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in <module>
    x = GradTA(name="Peter",school="Harvard",age=25,subject="Linear Algebra",major="Mathematics",advisor="Yau")
  File "<stdin>", line 29, in __init__
    GraduateStudent.__init__(self,age,name,school,major,advisor)
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in __init__
    super().__init__(age,name,school,major)
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(age,name,school)
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __init__
    super().__init__(age,name)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'school' and 'subject'
```

The error message suggests that the problem occurs when `Student.__init__()` calls `Person.__init__()`.

If I write `__init__()` in `Student` as

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.school = school
```

or

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,age,name,school):
        Person.__init__(self,age,name)
        self.school = school
```

, then everything works well.

But I still want to know what went wrong with my original use of `super()`.

Comment: `super()` isn't guaranteed to just call your _immediate_ superclass -- it walks the MRO; so everything in your MRO needs to be able to handle the calling convention you use.

Comment: You need to use `super` in all the classes that you are trying to use cooperative multiple inheritance. Mixing direct calls to some parent class `__init__` and `super` is bad

Comment: Look at the error message: what class's `__init__` is the problem point?  Trace how you got to that point.  Look up the resolution algorithm, and what happens when you chain your `super.__init__` invocations in this fashion.  If nothing else, put in some useful `print` commands to trace your execution.

Comment: Really worth a watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: Original blog post behind the above video: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it really helps clarifying my understanding of super(). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `super` invocation can't run the `__init__()` from a class it inherits from

You an fix this by adding `*args, **kwargs` to your init functions, which will allow passing arbitrary positional and named arguments to it and any classes which are using inheritance and super.

```py
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(school=school, *args, **kwargs)
        self.school = school
```

Comment: This won't pass `age` and `name` to `super().__init__` as will be expected by `Person`. Don't duplicate parameters in `Student.__init__`; just add the new ones introduced by `Student`, and let the ones required by `Person` be gathered in `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Comment: Should be already updated from copied; please make an edit otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

Only *new* parameters should be added to the signature of a subclass `__init__` method. Those intended to initialize *inherited* attributes will be part of `**kwargs` and passed on as necessary.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, *, age, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, *, school, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.school = school

class UniversityStudent(Student):
    def __init__(self, *, major, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.major = major

class GraduateStudent(UniversityStudent):
    def __init__(self, *, advisor, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.advisor = advisor

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self, *, subject, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.subject = subject

class GradTA(GraduateStudent,Teacher):
    pass

x = GradTA(name="Peter",school="Harvard",age=25,subject="Linear Algebra",major="Mathematics",advisor="Yau")
```

Notice that you don't need to override `__init__` in `GradTA`; there isn't anything it needs to do that isn't already done by either `GraduateStudent.__init__` or `Teacher.__init__`, and both are guaranteed to run (regardless of the order in which you list them as base classes) because both use `super` properly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the super() with class constructors

```
def answer(self):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();
```